Icecast nginx authorization issue
I am trying to use nginx with an icecast server to make the icecast server secure use https instead of just http. However I am running into the following error when I am trying to obtain a security certificate using the code
sudo certbot --nginx

However I get the following error
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Error while running nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t.
2024/08/10 22:16:42 [emerg] 226356#226356: "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
The nginx plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: MisconfigurationError('Error while running nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t.\n\n2024/08/10 22:16:42 [emerg] 226356#226356: "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1\nnginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed\n')
This is my configuration file I am using which I assume should be correct (of course with my domain instead of your domain.)
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name yourdomain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourdomain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

Not sure what I am doing wrong any suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks!

FYI, icecast supports HTTPS out of the box. You just need to provide it certificate files and preferably reconfigure it to run on port 443 (which requires you to execute as root and use the changeowner configuration). It's all reasonably well explained in quite a few posts on the net.
